# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; phpmyadmin online mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a stored procedure in which I am executing this query :

```
select
    c.*, p.title
from
(
    select *
    FROM
    (
        (select bobos.*, if (firstbobo=1 and idhoo is null, 0,1) as doe
         from bobos left join hoo
             on (bobos.idbobo = hoo.idbobo and hoo.status<2)
         where idko = pidko order by doe ASC limit 1
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (
        select bobos.*, 2
        from
        (
            select follows
            from bobos
            natural join hoo
            where bobos.idko = pidko and hoo<=>2
        ) a
        inner join bobos
            on a.follows=bobos.idbobo
    )) u
) c 
natural join
(
    select userid, title, kos.idko,
        sum(if(groupview is null,1,if(view is null,0,1))) as viewr,
        sum(if(groupy is null,1,if(y is null,0,1))) as y
    from kgs
    INNER JOIN groupkos
        on kos.idko=groupkoid or (groupview is null and  groupy is null)
    right join mv_groupuser
        on groupkoid=groupid and userid=piduser
    where kos.idko=pidko
    GROUP BY  userid,kos.idko 
    HAVING viewr>0 or y>0
    ORDER BY dated DESC LIMIT 1
) p ;
```

On my local computer this stored procedure is working well but when I try to important my sql file to phpmyadmin to my online server, phpmyadmin is giving me the following error :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near ') u) c

I have tried to play with parentheses but it is not working... I don't know what is wrong, I need help to fix the problem.

My online phpmyadmin is 4.7.7

Comment: I think you have an extra parenthesis in there (this, after a 5 minute laborious manual edit of your question, which you should have done yourself).  Clean up your query, and you should find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but I can't see where I have extra parenthesis ... as I said it working on my of line mysql server very well.... for cleaning up that's the best I can do... can you just indicate to me where you think I have an extra parathesis... I have tried to remove and add more but nothing is working: when I remove I get the following error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias